# Need help in R - take a count of high frequency data by day of week and hour

Tags: r

I am trying to build a matrix of rows = hours of the day (00 to 23) and columns = days of week (Mon to Sun). This is required to build a frequency (count) of ticks for my high frequency data across different hours of the day. Any suggestions?
e.g:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn9rq.jpg)

Comment: Please post example of wanted output.

Comment: `with(data, table(hours, days))` and replace `data` with name of matrix

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have now added a screenshot of sample data

Comment: @User7598, thank you very much. That has help!!!

Comment: @SidMark thanks... I added it as an answer please accept if it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try

`with(data, table(hours, days))` and replace `data` with name of matrix